# Utilizing the UIScrollView zoom method how do I save a zoomed video recording in the Apple AVCam Example Project?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use the Objective C AVCam Example Project from Apple to create a custom camera that uploads photos directly to my server. Using UIScrollView I can zoom the previewView and modify a captured still photo so that it appears zoomed just as in the previewView. However I cannot save a video in zoomed format. I have tried to modify AVCapureDevice (device.videoZoomFactor) as suggested in a previous SO response and have been trying to modify the images created from the NSURL of the video file (code snippets below) but nothing is working. Any suggestions/solutions/insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    return self.previewView;

}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput 
 didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections: 
   (NSArray *)connections
{

       self.videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL];

       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(changesizeofvideo) 
       withObject:nil];



        // Enable the Record button to let the user stop the recording.

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.recordButton.enabled = YES;
        [self.recordButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"Stop", @"Recording button stop title" ) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
}

-(void)changesizeofvideo{



    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:self.videoData];
    UIImageView *mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];



    float zoomScale = 1.0 / self.scrollView.zoomScale;

    CGRect rect;


    rect.origin.x = fabs(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    rect.origin.y = fabs(self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    rect.size.width = fabs(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * zoomScale);
    rect.size.height = fabs(self.scrollView.bounds.size.height * zoomScale);




UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(mainImageView.frame.size.width*zoomScale, mainImageView.frame.size.height*zoomScale)); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = CGPointMake( -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = mainImageView.frame.size.width;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = mainImageView.frame.size.height;

    [img drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    if(newImage == nil)
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.videoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1);

    //convert data to path
    NSString*path;
    [self.videoData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    //convert path to url
    //NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(preparImageForUpload) withObject:nil];

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput 
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL 
fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
/*
     Note that currentBackgroundRecordingID is used to end the background task
     associated with this recording. This allows a new recording to be started,
     associated with a new UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier, once the movie file output's
     `recording` property is back to NO — which happens sometime after this method
     returns.

     Note: Since we use a unique file path for each recording, a new recording will
     not overwrite a recording currently being saved.
     */
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier currentBackgroundRecordingID = self.backgroundRecordingID;
    self.backgroundRecordingID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    dispatch_block_t cleanUp = ^{
        if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFileURL.path] ) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFileURL.path error:NULL];
       }

       if ( currentBackgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid ) {
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:currentBackgroundRecordingID];
           }
       };

       BOOL success = YES;

       if ( error ) {
            NSLog( @"Movie file finishing error: %@", error );
            success = 
    [error.userInfo[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey] boolValue];
        }
        if ( success ) {
             // Check authorization status.


            self.videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: outputFileURL];

         [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(preparImageForUpload) withObject:nil];
       //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(changesizeofvideo) withObject:nil];


    }
    else {
        cleanUp();
    }

    // Enable the Camera and Record buttons to let the user switch camera and start another recording.
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Only enable the ability to change camera if the device has more than one camera.
        self.cameraButton.enabled = ( self.videoDeviceDiscoverySession.uniqueDevicePositionsCount > 1 );
        self.recordButton.enabled = YES;
        self.captureModeControl.enabled = YES;
        [self.recordButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"Record", @"Recording button record title" ) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
});
}


-(void)preparImageForUpload{
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    NSLog( @"TOOK A VIDEO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" );



    self.username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                 stringForKey:@"userName"];

    int randomnumONE =((arc4random_uniform(2764472319))) ;
    int randomnumTWO =((arc4random_uniform(2764472319))) ;
    int randomnumTHREE=((arc4random_uniform(2764472319))) ;
    self.largerrandomnumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d",randomnumONE,randomnumTWO,randomnumTHREE];


       // NSDate* today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSString*today = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];



    //name the file and then THIS PUTS PATH IN DATABASE
    //NSString * pathForFile= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@---%@", self.username, self.largerrandomnumber];
    NSString * pathForFile= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@---%@---%@", self.username,self.largerrandomnumber,today];

    // Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathForFile];

    //convert url to data
    //NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: outputFileURL];


    //call upload method with image data
    [self uploadImage:self.videoData filename:fileName];




}



- (BOOL)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData filename:(NSString *)filename{




    //THIS PUTS PHOTO INTO SERVER FILE

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myserveraddress.com";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request2 addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]);
     //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=%@",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request2 setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
    NSString * OKstring=@"OK";

    if([returnString isEqualToString:OKstring]){




    }else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                    message:@"Picture could not be uploaded."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Try again"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];


    }

      return ([returnString isEqualToString:@"OK"]);

}
```

Comment: is it really so hard to proof-read your own question and to properly indent the code? no one wants to read mis-indented code..

Comment: Please reformat and indent you code again. `Long time listener, first time caller....be gentle...please.` Not required at all. People always appreciate if you ask good and clear questions. Everyone here started from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this: After embedding the `previewView` into a `scrollview` I added these two methods and was able to zoom the camera and save the zoomed image:

```
  -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   {

        return self.previewView;

    }

 - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // if (scrollView.zoomBouncing) {

   if (scrollView.zoomScale <1) {
       dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
           NSError *error = nil;
        if ([self.videoDeviceInput.device lockForConfiguration:&error])
          {
            [self.videoDeviceInput.device rampToVideoZoomFactor:1 withRate:1];

            [self.videoDeviceInput.device unlockForConfiguration];
          }
          else
          {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
          }
      });
   }
   else
    if (scrollView.zoomScale >1) {
        NSLog(@"Bouncing back from minimum zoom");
        dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([self.videoDeviceInput.device lockForConfiguration:&error])
            {
                [self.videoDeviceInput.device 
                  rampToVideoZoomFactor:self.scrollView.zoomScale*2 
                withRate:1];

                [self.videoDeviceInput.device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
         });
      }

   }
```